# How to stream large csv in Spring4 rest api?

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring 4 web-mvc to create a rest api. I have a gigantic csv file that I want to stream. In python I can do very simple:

```
from flask import Response

@app.route('/large.csv')
def generate_large_csv():
    def generate():
        for row in iter_all_rows():
            yield ','.join(row) + '\n'
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

What is the equivalent in Spring 4? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is pseudo code as a hint for you:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/large.csv", method = GET, produces = "text/csv")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void streamLargeCSV(OutputStream output) {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(csvFile);
    int read=0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 4];  //size per read

    while((read = is.read(bytes))!= -1){
        output.write(bytes, 0, read);
        output.flush();  //may change flush rate to more rows/flush
    }
    output.close()
}
```

Comment: My csv is 16GB, my memory is 4GB. My memory will not crash from this right?

Comment: Basically you need to read your file as streaming as well.  Let me update my answer to read from file.

Comment: In spring usually I return something like a String or something, but in your code you use a "void", would it actually return to the browser without using any return statement?

Comment: As for this one, we inject `OutputStream output`. Therefore, no return value required.