# Java creating and download a file using ajax not working

Tags: java, ajax, file, spring-mvc

I am trying to generate some reports and download as `csv file` using my `Java Spring MVC Web Application`. I have a list of data displayed on the browser with option to select multiple rows and the I am trying to create a csv file with selected rows and download the csv file. My controller method is as follows:

```
public String downloadBusinessAsFile(@ModelAttribute("ids") String selectedIds, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model)
{
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'.csv'").format(new Date());
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName);
    try 
    {
        Map<String, Obj> sessionBusinesses = (Map<String, Obj>) httpSession.getAttribute("objMap");
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        StringBuffer sb = reportService.writeBusinessesToCSV(selectedIds, sessionData);         
        InputStream in = 
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        //copy binary contect to output stream
        while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
        {
            out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        httpSession.invalidate();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "success"; 
}
```

`StringBuffer` object returned has the required value. I am using the following scripts to call the controller method:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-biz', function(){ 
    var selectedRow = '';
    for (var i = 0; i< $('#datTable tbody tr.selected').length; i++) 
    {
         if (i <= 0) 
         {
             selectedRow+=$('#datTable tbody tr.selected')[i].id;              
         }
        else 
        {
            selectedRow+=','+$('#datTable tbody tr.selected')[i].id;
        }
    }
    var url = $("#addUrl").val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : url,
        type: "GET",
        data : {ids: selectedRow},
        dataType : "html",
        success:function(htmlData) 
        {   
            if(htmlData == "error")
            {
                $('#btn-div').html("<p>An error occurred</p>")
            }
            else
            {
                $("#successAlert").show();
            }
            $('#divLoading').hide();
        },
        error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
            console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
            console.dir( xhr );
        },
    });
});
```

I do not get any error while running the code but do not see any download option.

Comment: For the client side part see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax/7660817#7660817

Comment: For the server side part see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552561/how-to-stream-large-csv-in-spring4-rest-api

Comment: dont use ajax to download file use hidden form approach or general form to hit mapped method follow the link might it will help  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351582/7924858